# Notation - Tensor product of dirac deltas

Tags: real-analysis, tensor-products, dirac-delta

In a paper I'm reading I found some notation I've never seen before. For some functions $f,g$ and $h$ they write
$$\delta_f\otimes\delta_g\otimes\delta_h.$$
What does this expression mean? I guess it's pretty standard.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: what is the context ? finite dimensional vector spaces, or function spaces ? it'd make more sense if $f,g,h$ were indices as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Dimension ,  not functions

Comment: $f,g,h$ are functions which are solutions of a system of ODE's. They call this tensor product the empirical distribution function.